# Upgrade Pig on HDInsight Emulator

Tags: azure, hadoop, apache-pig, azure-hdinsight

I am currently using the HDInsight Hadoop Emulator, which comes with Pig Version .12.  Our problem involves parsing xml files and I'd like to use the XPath command from PiggyBank, but it is only available with Pig version .13.

a. Can I Upgrade Pig in the emulator?  How would I go about doing that?
b. Is the version of Pig really critical, or could I just get the latest version of the PiggyBank.jar file and use that?

Answer (score 1):

currently there is no way to update component versions for HDInsight emulator (or at least that's very hard to do). 
I have never used PiggyBank, but from the introduction page (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/PIG/PiggyBank) it seems that it is a collection of UDFs which should work with Pig 0.12. So i guess using the jar directly (and of course registering it in pig) should work.

Also, we are looking for an updated story for HDInsight emulator - so feel free to reach us at hdivstool at microsoft dot com if you have any thoughts, comments, requirements.

Xiaoyong Zhu from HDInsight team